# Why is RNN no weigth between hidden and output?

Tags: python, recurrent-neural-network

PyTorch RNN has `RNN.weight_ih`, which is a weight between input and hidden layer, and `RNN.weight_hh`, which is a weight between hidden and hidden. Why is there no weight between hidden and output?

[image: schematic of unrolled RNN showing the three weight matrices]

When I was learning about RNNs, I learned that there are 3 weights.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no weight there because the PyTorch `RNN` doesn’t prescribe how to create the output from the hidden state. When you apply the `RNN` to a sequence, it returns the sequence of hidden states.

You can decide what to do with these: maybe a linear transformation is the right way to get the output (as you learned it). Maybe you don’t need the outputs, except for the final one. In that case, you can save O(T) computations by only computing the final output, manually.